# After plugin activation all users marked as Spam

Tags: plugins, buddypress

I want to use Buddy Press. I `ve installed it, activated, then I automatically logged out.
When I want to log me in – there is a message – my account is marked as spam. My Testaccount too. I think all my Users will see this message if they want to login…

I named the plugin folder in plugin.hold – I could log in. I delete the folder BuddyPress and rename the folder, all works. I`ve deactivated all plugins and try to install buddy press again – same fault

Please help me

Thank you very much